# Horizontal viewport was given unbounded height, probably from ListView.builder

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am trying to build screen and display pictures choosen by user with ListView.builder(), but it throws an error and don't display it

I tried using SizedBox and shrinkWrap: true, but it doesn't work

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<File> pictures = widget.pictures;

    final size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    final width = size.width;
    final height = size.height;

    Widget buildPicture(BuildContext ctxt, int index) {
      return Container(
          width: 300,
          height: 300,
          child: Image.file(pictures[index])
      );
    }

    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Display the Picture')),

        body: ListView(
            physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                child: Text('Nové hlášení'),
              ),
              Container(
                height: height / 5,
                child: ListView(
                  physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text('Fotografie'),
                    ListView.builder(
                      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                      itemCount: pictures.length,
                      itemBuilder: (BuildContext ctxt, int index) => buildPicture(ctxt, index)
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              )
            ]
        )

      //Image.file(File(widget.imagePath)),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Try to use physics: ClampingScrollPhysics()

Comment: @RohitSingh Unfortunately, it doesn't help :/

Comment: Why do you have a ListView inside a ListView inside a ListView?

Comment: @F-1 Because I need to have Text before the ListView.builder

Comment: Sorry I don't understand, do you have an illustration? I'm guessing using a row or column isn't suitable? Anyway, try wrapping the offending widget in an 'Expanded' widget https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Expanded-class.html